# Is there an obvious link between Analysis and Group theory?

Tags: group-theory, analysis

For instance, Number theory can be seen as a subfield of Analysis, and Linear algebra is indeed definitely a subfield of Group theory - and both might in fact be generalised under some area of studies between Set theory and Group theory that I have not come across yet.

The question is, is there such a field that contains Analysis and Group theory as subfields?  Or in other words, is there an obvious link between Analysis and Group theory?

Comment: If you consider Number theory as a subfield of Analysis and Linear algebra definitely as a subfield of Group theory, then Analysis should clearly be a subfield of Group theory…

Comment: Lie groups?${}$

Comment: I see.  First time hearing of this.  I'm looking into it now.  Thanks.

Comment: "Number theory can be seen as a subfield of Analysis, and Linear algebra is indeed definitely a subfield of Group theory" Why do you believe this? (Note that vector spaces involve fields as well as groups, and that [algebraic number theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_theory) is a thing.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Interesting, I think what I need is a proper/detailed "map" of mathematics.  My naive understanding of some of these areas seems somewhat flawed.

Comment: There really isn't that easy of a "map" of mathematics. Algebra and analysis are the language of mathematics and as such there's a lot of interplay between them. Algebraic topology for example is a huge field that contains elements of both, where you use algebra to probe the topology (and by extension the types of functions so analysis) on a space.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question   because it's much too broad. In the meanwhile, I recommend the map of mathematics: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OmJ-4B-mS-Y

Comment: @Stephen Number theory **is not** a subfield of analysis. Have you heard about [Algebraic Number Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_theory)? Don't bother trying to draw a proper map of mathematics. Not only it can't be done because at some level everything is connect but also it doesn't really give you anything. These labels are just loose, intuitive groupings of topics.

Comment: I believe you might be write Freakish.  What I find interesting nonetheless is how some of these are connected.  In this particular case, Analysis and GT.  Lie groups are starting to look like the answer.

Comment: @EthanBolker  I don't think this should be closed.  I think it will help others asking similar questions to get a simple and quick answer.  (The answer might seem obvious to any professional, but not so much to people like myself who have just began to dive into these areas.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the fact that "analysis" and "group theory" are different classification levels (like "plants" and "vertebrates" in biology), all things related to [Lie Groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) form a significant mix of analysis and group theory.

Answer (score 2):

There is something called Topological Groups which can carry (the locally compact ones) a Haar measure, comparable to Riemann or Lebesgue. You can “do analysis” with these kinds of groups.